# swift - Activate segue on a class from model file outside of a class? Instance member cannot be used on type

Tags: swift, model

My app has a model file where I check my API.  If the network check fails with a specific code (token inactive), I want the app to segue back to the log in page.

My challenge is that the API call is stored in my model file, not in a view controller class.

Is there a way to activate the segue from the model file outside of the actual class?

I tried to make a logout function on my TabBarController class and use this in my model to activate the segue:

```
class InitialTabBarController: UITabBarController {
...
    func logoutFresh(){
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "logoutFresh", sender: self)
    }

}
```

Then in my model I added:

```
func pullAPIData(){
...
if httpResponse == 403 {
InitialTabBarController.logoutFresh()
    }
}
```

I call the pullAPIData() function in another view controller class (one of the viewControllers in the tabBarController

However, this gives an error that:
Instance member 'logoutFresh' cannot be used on type 'InitialTabBarController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Is there a way check if the InitialTabBarController is active and then have it initiate the segue from the model file?  Or a better way to handle this?

Comment: what about storing the data in core data? or creating a global boolean variable that changes? ALSO you should store this token in a functions file that is NOT associated to any view controller so that you can use it anywhere

Comment: You could use NotificationCenter and post the notification from your model and listen in your ViewController.

Comment: Thanks David - that seems to have worked.  Very simple solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, iOS uses the delegation pattern or the completion handler patters to solve this type of scenarios;

In delegation pattern, you set a weak variable in your model class that points to your viewcontroller. So that once your network call is completed, you can use this delegate to call a function in the view controller

In completion handler patter, you send a code block that should be executed after your api call is completed as follows:

```
func pullAPIData(completion: () -> Void){
    //do your stuff
    completion()
}
```

Your can refer the following posts to get a better understanding of delegates and completion handlers:
https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef
https://medium.com/@nimjea/completion-handler-in-swift-4-2-671f12d33178